# How to have both Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows 8 and for Windows Desktop in one?

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2012

I have installed both of above, but they are installed as two completely separate IDEs! In the RC version, I could program both metro-style apps and desktop apps in one. It's very unpractical to have two Visual Studios. Is there a way to merge these IDEs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't combine them.

The Express editions are designed to be separate programs for separate tasks.

If you want an all-in-one IDE then you have to purchase a full version of Visual Studio (Professional for example).

Comment: Be aware too that there are other free options as well depending on your qualifications.  Students at accredited institutions can get Microsoft tools free via DreamSpark and entrepreneurs/startups can apply for BizSpark.

Comment: @JimO'Neil: yes, I am a student, with no ISIC and school not listed (but there are primary schools!! I don't really think pupils of these schools needs development tools...)

Comment: I don't have all the details on eligibility, but you can certainly send a note to https://www.dreamspark.com/student/support.aspx and see what they say.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for Visual Studio Professional or higher (as opposed to Express), which does everything.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Buy the full product.  If cost is an issue for you, I'm afraid you will have to live with having 2 IDEs installed.

Comment: I would rather live with 10 IDEs installed than to pay that unfair price.

Comment: @Matej: Unfair price? Express is free and comes at the cost of separate IDEs. Very handy for the self-employed developer, hobby developer or employees of larger companies wanting to try out things at home in their own time. However, if you are a company with several employees and need to pay for licensing and get the all-in-one IDE one would assume you are producing applications or offering services in your company making you well more than 3-5k a year. If you are looking to make money using the tools you are going to have to pay money to use them. That is only fair... no?